# Create a chain of tasks

Tags: c#, task

I'm writing a background service which pulls historical data about products while my web server is running.  I can only make requests at a specific rate, so for that reason, I need to create an executionQueue:

Creating this list of tasks is verbose and I don't see why it should be like this.
Maybe I'm just over complicating things:

```
public List<Task<Task<List<Candle>>>> BuildHistoricalDataTaskList(CryptoInfoContext context, string productId, DateTime totalStartDate, DateTime totalEndDate, Granularity[] granularities, int maxResults = 300)
{
    var product = this.GetProductFromId(context, productId);
    var executionQueue = new List<Task<Task<List<Candle>>>>();
    foreach (var granularity in granularities)
    {
        var granularityMinutes = (int)granularity;
        var startDate = totalStartDate;
        var maxRangeMinutes = maxResults * granularityMinutes;

        while (startDate <= totalEndDate)
        {
            var endDate = startDate.AddMinutes(maxRangeMinutes);
            var task = new Task<Task<List<Candle>>>(() =>
            {
                return ProcessHistoricalDataAsync(productId, startDate, endDate, granularity);
            });

            executionQueue.Add(task);
            startDate = endDate;
        }
    }

    return executionQueue;
}
```

My return type seems a little verbose, is there a way i'm able to squash these Tasks down?

Maybe an observable is the way to go but I'm not sure how.

Comment: What does a `Task<Task<List<Candle>>>` represent?  What does that unused `CryptoInfoContext` parameter represent?

Comment: @Flydog57 originally I was going to save the results in my db as well, but I realized I needed to do it separately because entity framework does not like async execution on the same context.

Comment: Since I need to limit the rate of my requests I've created an execution queue to be send to function which handles executing these tasks at a specific rate but I don't like that I needed to return a task from my task, I feel like I should be able to squash them down into a single task

Comment: Depending on your full pipeline, you *might* try using TPL Data Flow and throttling

Comment: Thanks I'll look into throttling directly from the TPL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the middle Task is just behaving as a late execution closure. So you could replace that with a `Func<Task<List<Candle>>>` and get the same effect. That doesn't help anything, but it reduces the confusion introduced by `Task<Task<...>>`.

I'm assuming outside of this is something that processes the queue, so could you slim it down to an `IEnumerable<Func<Task<List<Candle>>>>`?

eg.

```
public IEnumerable<Func<Task<List<Candle>>>> BuildHistoricalDataTaskList(CryptoInfoContext context, string productId, DateTime totalStartDate, DateTime totalEndDate, Granularity[] granularities, int maxResults = 300)
{
    var product = this.GetProductFromId(context, productId);
    foreach (var granularity in granularities)
    {
        var granularityMinutes = (int)granularity;
        var startDate = totalStartDate;
        var maxRangeMinutes = maxResults * granularityMinutes;

        while (startDate <= totalEndDate)
        {
            var endDate = startDate.AddMinutes(maxRangeMinutes);
            yield return () =>
            {
                return ProcessHistoricalDataAsync(productId, startDate, endDate, granularity);
            };
            
            startDate = endDate;
        }
    }
}
```

it's not much better from a signature perspective. But it's slightly smaller.. Also you're not using `product` at all, that's likely costing you something.